# Почему рефлексия медленнее, чем прямое обращение?

Tags: c#, .net

Если верить различным источникам, то доп. время тратится на то, что бы проверить существование того или иного свойства+ используются всякие таблицы с метаданными.

Однако, почему повторное обращение к тому же полю не ~= прямому доступу к полю? Ведь, первый раз мы все проверили => все можно закешировать.

Comment: Что, например, закешировать?

Comment: @tym32167 Например название/сигнатуру метода и линк на этот метод.

Comment: @Andrew хотел наводящими вопросами автора подвести к выводу, но внезапно накатал ответ

Comment: @tym32167 у всех бывает)

Comment: Для вызова метода можно создать делегат и кешировать его. Для свойства тоже, думаю

Comment: Вот мне интересно, если вы плюсуете ответы, значит вопрос интересен, почему тогда у него так мало плюсов по сравнению с ответами? Или я не понимаю что то?

Comment: @НарутоУзумаки как же приятно от того факта, что даже Хокаге из деревни шиноби занялся изучением c#. PS: я бы еще добавил бы тэг `c# faq`, наверное... Вопрос-то хороший.

Answer (score 13):

Это не рефлексия медленная, это прямой вызов быстрый.

Компиляция в C# работает в два этапа. На первом этапе раз ваш код компилируется в IL. И на уровне IL прямой вызов действительно смотрится ненамного медленнее, чем вызов через рефлексию - это все еще вызов метода по куску метаданных.

При выполнении приложения код компилируется еще раз, из IL в JIT. Основные оптимизации срабатывают именно на этом этапе.

Предположим у нас есть код вида

```
class SomeClass
{
    public int SomeProp { get; set; }
}

[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
static int SomeMethod(SomeClass instance)
{
    // Debugger.Launch();
    return instance.SomeProp;
}
```

B IL он выглядит как

```
.method private hidebysig static int32  SomeMethod(class ConsoleApp15.Program/SomeClass 'instance') cil managed noinlining
// SIG: 00 01 08 12 0C
{
  // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
  // Code size       13 (0xd)
  .maxstack  8
  .language '{3F5162F8-07C6-11D3-9053-00C04FA302A1}', '{994B45C4-E6E9-11D2-903F-00C04FA302A1}', '{5A869D0B-6611-11D3-BD2A-0000F80849BD}'
// Source File 'C:\Users\pavelp\source\repos\ConsoleApp15\ConsoleApp15\Program.cs' 
//000021:             Debugger.Launch();
//  IL_0000:  /* 28   | (0A)000010       */ call       bool [mscorlib]System.Diagnostics.Debugger::Launch()
//  IL_0005:  /* 26   |                  */ pop
//000022:             return instance.SomeProp;
  // загрузили значение instance (адрес объекта) в стек
  IL_0006:  /* 02   |                  */ ldarg.0 
  // вызвали метод (геттер) у объекта, лежащего в стеке
  IL_0007:  /* 6F   | (06)000004       */ callvirt   instance int32 ConsoleApp15.Program/SomeClass::get_SomeProp()
  IL_000c:  /* 2A   |                  */ ret
} // end of method Program::SomeMethod
```

Как видите, компилятор C# вшил конкретные токены метаданных в IL (`(06)000004` - это токен `get_SomeProp`), но вызов свойства все еще на месте. При выполнении "как есть" все еще надо лезть в таблицу метаданных, искать там адрес метода-геттера и вызывать его.

И вот JIT компилирует метод `SomeMethod`.

В случае обычного, невиртуального, автосгенерированного свойства JIT видит конкретную реализацию свойства, и знает, что

- Реализация свойства - это просто возврат значения.
- У свойства нет сайдэффектов.
- Нет никаких дополнительных проверок на права доступа (конструкции public / private - это ограничения уровня языка, а не уровня рантайма).
- Backing Field для свойства во всех экземплярах класса SomeClass лежит в одном и том же месте.

Все это позволяет JIT-у взять и заменить вызов свойства на доставание значения поля напрямую, по адресу объекта + смещению этого поля от начала объекта. Окончательный нативный код SomeMethod будет выглядеть вот так:

```
00007FFA323B04DD  mov         eax,dword ptr [rsi+8]
```

Это *полный код* вызова свойства + реализация самого свойства в момент реального выполнения. В `rsi` в этот момент лежит адрес instance, `8` - смещение backing field поля от начала объекта типа SomeClass. `MOV r64,m64` - это один такт процессора+задержка в пару тактов на доставание значения из кэша.

---

В случае же рефлексии вызов останется полноценным вызовом, пусть и косвенным. Даже если вы закэшируете метаданные - в коде все равно останется вызов метода у объекта типа PropertyInfo, которому придется достать адрес конкретного свойства, залезть в объект и вызвать геттер. Как бы ни был оптимизирован PropertyInfo, как бы быстро код ни работал - он все равно будет медленнее чем просто `MOV`.

Comment: _"это не рубль слабеет, а доллар дорожает"_ Как бы то ни было, плюс.

Answer (score 9):

Слово *медленная* не очень точное. Рефлексия медленнее прямого обращения в десятки раз, но на современных процессорах это означает, что вместо нескольких наносекунд рефлексия работает несколько десятков, может быть, сотен наносекунд. Этого быстродействия хватает для многих приложений.

И, не смотря на то, что рефлексия медленнее, это не должно служить причиной отказа от неё. Меня лично больше смущает то, что рефлексия переносит часть проверок с времени компиляции на время выполнения, что лишает вас плюсов статической типизации. В общем, смотрите на обстоятельства, и пусть скорость не будет единственным критерием для принятия решения.

Теперь ответ на вопрос «почему». Сразу скажу: всё, что ниже, передано в общих чертах. Процессоры умеют выполнять операции параллельно, они пытаются предсказать, что будет дальше, поэтому говорить про точные количества тактов и наносекунд я не буду. Все числа, которые будут дальше — среднепотолочные.

Возьмём простую операцию: получение значения свойства. Если речь идёт об обычном не-виртуальном свойстве, то для получения значения вызывается метод, адрес которого известен на этапе компиляции.

Если речь идёт о статическом свойстве, ты мы просто вызываем функцию, которая в большинстве случаев заносит результат в один из регистров процессора и тут же возвращает управление Все эти операции выполняются буквально за несколько тактов.

Если речь идёт о свойстве объекта (экземпляра), то перед вызовом функции мы заносим в регистр адрес объекта, а сам геттер берёт значение из оперативной памяти, вычисляя адрес поля относительно начала объекта. Это тоже очень быстро, но в 1,5-2 раза медленнее, чем в первом случае.

*Предыдущие два метода JIT сумеет оптимизировать. Вместо того, чтобы вызывать простой метод, компилятор может «встроить» его код в вызывающий метод. В результате мы можем избавиться от вызова и возврата управления, и получить буквально одну машинную инструкцию.*

Если речь идёт о виртуальном свойстве, то у нас появляется *косвенная адресация вызова*. Компилятор уже не знает адрес метода, но знает его порядковый номер в *таблице виртуальных функций*. Каждый объект перед самым первым полем хранит заголовок со служебными данными, в том числе и адрес этой таблицы. В общем, вызов виртуального метода занимает чуть больше времени, скажем, он работает ещё в 3-4 раза медленнее.

Поскольку компилятор на этапе компиляции может проверить типы значений, и знает смещения полей относительно начала объекта, машинный код в каждом из этих случаев получается весьма простым.

Теперь, предположим, мы хотим получить значение свойства через рефлексию. Сначала мы ищем описатель свойства по имени.

```
var propInfo = typeof(MyClass).GetProperty("propertyName");
```

Поиск может оказаться довольно сложным. Представим, что поле описано не в самом классе `MyClass`, а в предке его предка. Не заглядывая в исходники, трудно сказать, какова трудоёмкость этого поиска, но понятно, что это не элементарная операция.

В то же время, именно эту часть мы можем закэшировать, сохранив `PropertyInfo` для дальнейшего использования.

Далее, мы получаем значение:

```
var value = (int)propInfo.GetValue(myObject);
```

Метод `GetValue` получит из `propInfo` адрес функции-геттера и вызовет её. Функция вернёт `ValueObject`, а метод `GetValue` должен будет проверить это, и запаковать значение в объект (то, что по английски называется *boxing*).

Объект будет выделен в куче, значение свойства будет скопировано туда, и адрес объект вернётся в ваш метод. Затем будет преобразование типа в `int`, которое сначала проверит, возможно ли это преобразование. И затем значение будет скопировано из кучи в локальную переменную `value`.

Мы видим, что здесь у нас большое количество проверок и вычислений. Вместо регистров мы передаём значение через кучу, у нас есть ветвления, которые нам приходится делать и внутри `GetValue`, и снаружи — при приведении типа.

Именно поэтому рефлексия медленнее прямого обращения.

Answer (score 7):

Не очень точный перевод [ответа от Джона Скита](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3502710/312041). Ответ про java, то в C#, по сути, те же проблемы

---

Когда вы используете рефлексию, каждое ваше действие требует множество проверок. Например, когда вы вызываете какой-либо метод, объект, метод которого вы вызываете, будет проверен на соотвествие типу, на то, что метод в этом объекте присутствует, что передано ожидаемое количество параметров, что каждый параметр имеет именно тот тип, с которым метод может быть вызван.

Нет никакой возможности избежать подобных проверок или встроить их (inline).

Если, к примеру, вы кешируете ваши типы/методы в словарь, то вам придется выполнять поиск в словаре при каждом обращении к типу/методу по имени, а JIT этот поиск выполнит всего 1 раз.

В принципе, при использовании рефлексии просиходит много всего. Однако рефлексия стала намного быстрее, чем было раньше. Потому, если скорость работы рефлексии яляется проблемой для вас, вероятно, вы ей просто злоупотребляете и вам стоит пересмотреть ваш подход к решению ваших задач.

---

Также, если вы поглядите на код для работы со [свойствами](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/reflection/propertyinfo.cs,33abc272fbc5d11b) или, например, [вызова функции](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/reflection/methodinfo.cs,6845434f8724dd24), то, в принципе, становится ясно, почему вызов через рефлексию медленней обычного вызова.

Comment: `Нет никакой возможности избежать подобных проверок` -- почему нет? От части проверок можно избавится кешируя вручную `member Info` . А автор и спрашивает, 'почему повторное обращение к тому же полю не ~= прямому доступу к полю? Ведь, первый раз мы все проверили => все можно закешировать' . Как по мне, то вопрос умный и логичный. А вот ответ отвечает просто "никак нельзя".

Comment: @Andrew не очень вас понял. Вот, например, [проверка аргументов](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/reflection/methodinfo.cs,712), как ее избежать?

Comment: Не уверен в состоянии ли я аргументированно сейчас вести беседу, т.к. в даную секунду я далеко не трезв... Уж простите... НО!!! 1. точно возможно кешировать `MemberInfo` и 2. чисто теоретически возможно кешировать сам метод вместе с всеми аргументами (искать и проверять только 1 раз). Я сейчас рассуждаю теоретически. Тот же делегат -- это референс на метод с конкретными аргументами. Если мы можем сохранить такой референс, значит уже можно и закешировать такой референс после нахождения рефлексией. Хотя я не знаю как именно :D Уж простите.

Comment: @Andrew с кешированием никто не спорит, там больше имеются ввиду вещи, которые происходят, когда у вас уже есть MemberInfo и вы через него что то вызываете

Answer (score 7):

## Коротко:

1. Встроенного кеширования нет. Его можно написать самому
2. оно будет все равно медленнее чем доступ по методу напрямую или по делегату

## Долго:

Допустим у нас есть код:

```
public string GetViaReflection()
{
    PropertyInfo property = @class.GetProperty("Data", bindingFlags);

    return (string)property.GetValue(testClass, null);
}
```

это будет код без кеширования. Здесь "кеширование" будет только внутри самого метода. То есть первый вызов будет самым тяжелым, все последующие -- менее тяжелыми. Но у нас тут всего один вызов метода, так что каждый раз при вызове метода будет проделыватся вся работа с нуля.

Если же закешировать PropertyInfo извне метода:

```
//код который запускается только 1 раз
PropertyInfo cachedPropertyInfo = @class.GetProperty("Data", bindingFlags);

[Benchmark]
public string GetViaReflection()
{    
    return (string)cachedPropertyInfo.GetValue(testClass, null);
}
```

То любой вызов станет более быстрым. То есть, формально, **задача кеширования лежит на твоих плечах.** Но при этом, вызоа рефлексией будет все равно значительно тяжелее чем вызов по делегату или прямой вызов.

> почему так -- прекрасно описал Mark Shevchenko в своем ответе. А так же можешь почитать на английском линку ниже

Вот, например, [статья с тестами проведенными на эту тему](https://mattwarren.org/2016/12/14/Why-is-Reflection-slow/). По линке можно найти обьяснения и детали на английском, здесь же я оставлю просто табличку-результат тестов (там тестировались те 2 блока кода что я приводил выше):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я не уверен, закешировали ли они ПРАВИЛЬНО все и можно ли закешировать "более глубоко"... Но буду надеятся что они сделали все как нужно.

Это я к чему...  Возможно, есть возможность закешировать и обращение к самому методу, а не только к мемберу который его содержит. Формально, сохранить референс на метод с конкретным набором параметров -- как в делегат. Но там, по линке, это сделано не было.

Да, я знаю что я не ответил на главный вопрос автора:

> Однако, почему повторное обращение к тому же полю не ~= прямому доступу к полю? Ведь, первый раз мы все проверили => все можно закешировать.

Но хотя бы частично показал что автор вопроса прав и кеширование возможно, оно вполне работает и это подтверждается тестами. **Но оно реализуется только вручную в случае надобности.**

**Так же, формально, автором был задан вопрос, но НЕ НАПРЯМУЮ:**

> почему это не кешируется в рантайме автоматически, что бы сделать значительно более быстрыми последующие вызовы.

Уверен, этот вариант рассматривался разработчиками шарпа. И, думаю, он был откинут как раз таки в угоду быстродействию/количеству занимаемой памяти приложением. Никто не гарантирует того, что этот метод будет вызыватся более одного раза. Так что и кешировать его ВСЕГДА будет лишним. Если же пользователь нуждается в кешировании - он всегда может реализовать его сам.

Но аргументировать свои слова, увы, я не могу. Поэтому это просто ИМХО.

---

Так же для тебя могут быть интересными следующие ссылки с более быстрыми альтернативами рефлексии:

https://github.com/buunguyen/fasterflect

https://www.nuget.org/packages/FastMember
и маленький урок по FastMember: https://blog.marcgravell.com/2012/01/playing-with-your-member.html

Comment: Ну касательно "откинуто разработчиками из-за занимаемой памяти" маловероятно... Всегда можно дать какой-то выбор, например, булевский флаг в конце.